# object returns not defined in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi i am trying to get my head around some basic stuff in javascript, i want to create the equivalent to a class 
see below:

```
var myTest = {
  myTester:"testing",
  testCode:function(){
    return myTester;
 }
};
```

when i call `alert(myTest.testCode());`  i get error myTester is undefined;

i also have similar trouble when trying to set the value of myTester too, what i am trying to achieve here is something along the lines of this:

```
var myObj = myTest.testCode();
var tester = myObj.myTester;
```

as myObj is an object i should once created be able to access its values but i dont usually do javascript just jQuery and i am 
trying to create an application in pure javascript just for brain feed and would appreciate a little guidence, especially on what do you actually call this, is it a class????

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to access `this`:

```
var myTest = {
  myTester:"testing",
  testCode:function(){
    return this.myTester;
 }
};
```

Explanation: In each function, `this` refers to the context the function is called in. If you call a function with `func()` then `this` will refer to the global object (`window` in browser).
If you call `obj.func()` then `this` will refer to `obj`.

This is the only connection between a function and an object. The mere fact that you define a function as property of an object does **not** make the function aware of that object.

Functions are first class objects in JavaScript and as such not bound to any object (or class) (like in other languages, e.g. Java).

---

But

```
var myObj = myTest.testCode();
var tester = myObj.myTester;
```

would not work, as `myTest.testCode()` returns the string `"testing"` (and strings don't have a `myTester` property). If you want to make this code work, you would have to return `this` in `testCode`:

```
var myTest = {
  myTester:"testing",
  testCode:function(){
    return this;
 }
};
```

but then, the two lines are identical to

```
var tester = myTest.myTester;
```

---

I suggest to read some introduction to JavaScript, e.g. [***MDC - JavaScript Guide***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) and read especially about objects.

P.S.: To be very correct, classes don't exist in JavaScript. Only objects and constructor functions.

Comment: how can i get multiple values as above may be a bum example,   i.e myTester:null, myTester2:null,testCode()function(){ this.myTester="123"; this.myTester2 = "456"; }

How would i get myTester and myTester2's value which would depend on what happened in testcode   if you get my meaning  thanks

Comment: @minus4: Well, if your object is stored in `var myTest = {}`. Then you would do: `myTest.testCode();` and after that you can access the values via `myTest.myTester` or `myTest.myTester2`. But you don't need to store the return value of `testCode()` as you don't return anything anyway.

Comment: wicked yep tried that its all comming together :-)  thanks pal

Answer (score 0):

What you have in your example wouldn't be called a class, in my opinion, as it has no constructor function. At this point, it's just an object.

As mentioned by Felix Kling, you need to explicitly use `this` to refer to properties of your object from within its methods.

This example will not work to do what you want:

```
var myObj = myTest.testCode();
var tester = myObj.myTester;
```

The `testCode` method (once fixed to use `this`), returns the `myTester` property (a string). That string doesn't itself have a `myTester` property, so the `tester` variable will contain `undefined`.

You could instead just do

```
var tester = myTest.myTester;
```

To step back, the general pattern for a class could be something like this:

```
MyClass = function(initialValue) {
  this._myProperty = initialValue;
}

MyClass.prototype = {
  getMyProperty: function() {
    return this._myProperty;
  },

  setMyProperty: function(value) {
    this._myProperty = value;
  }
};

var myObj = new MyClass("test");
alert(myObj.getMyProperty());
myObj.setMyProperty("something");
```